# Accessing an element of an array according to a variable for a HighCharts object

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to generate a Spider Chart using HighCharts library.
Our data, however, varies a lot and includes some very small numbers and some very large ones.
If displayed, they make the Spider Chart to degenerate into a line.
So I implemented a pre-processing stage in which I normalise the values across each dimension.
The Spider Chart is now displayed properly, but tooltips are compromised as they display the normalised values instead of the absolute ones.
In order to keep track of both groups of values, I added a `ttip` array in the `series` object, as follows:

```
$('#hcRadar').highcharts({
  ...
  series: [{
    name: 'max(rec(9))',
    data: [1.0, 0.034440171953752756, 0.9724749421689427, 0.9937086214393859, 0.021795139861960203],
    ttip: [307.54340875,-1595.182889375,5045200000.0,831.187495625,-1664.2022475],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }, { 
    ...
  }]    
});
```

Now, tooltips are formatted according the following statement:

```
$('#hcRadar').highcharts({
  ...
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
  },
  ...
});
```

I discovered that the absolute values are accessible at `series.userOptions.ttip`, while the index to get the proper item out of it is `point.x`. I would like to use the latter to access the right element of the first, but I had no success because I am not much familiar with JS/JSON. I read many advice on this and other sites, but I wasn't able to solve my problem because I don't get what I am trying to do and what is wrong. Could you please help me to understand and solve the issue? I'd appreciate if you could also link some very very basic and introductory guide to catch the basic concepts of this technologies. Thanks in advance!

What I am trying to do follows:

```
pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{series.userOptions.ttip[point.x],.2f}</b><br/>'
```

The code `{series.userOptions.ttip.0:,.2f}` correctly returns `307.54` (and accordingly does for other sets of data), `{series.userOptions.ttip.1:,.2f}` returns `-1595.18` and so on... but then the values are obviously the same for each axe of the chart...

---

**Minimal** (non-) **Working Example**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Radar/Spider Chart</title>
<!-- jQuery - required by other -->
<script src="./scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./scripts/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/exporting.src.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 
<h1>Radar/Spider Chart</h1>
<h2>HighCharts</h2>
<p><div id="hcRadar" style="min-width: 480px; max-width: 640px; height: 480px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#hcRadar').highcharts({

    chart: {
      polar: true,
      type: 'line'
    },

    title: {
    text: 'Pareto-optimal plans for given objectives',
      x: -80
    },

    pane: {
      size: '80%'
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['rec(9)', 'rec(2)', 'cost', 'rec(10)', 'rec(5)'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      lineWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: {
      gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
      lineWidth: 0,
      min: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.2f}</b><br/>'
      // pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{series.userOptions.ttip.0:,.2f}</b><br/>'
    },

    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 70,
      layout: 'vertical'
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'max(rec(9))',
      data: [1.0, 0.034440171953752756, 0.9724749421689427, 0.9937086214393859, 0.021795139861960203],
      ttip: [307.54340875,-1595.182889375,5045200000.0,831.187495625,-1664.2022475],
      pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
      name: 'max(rec(2))',
      data: [0.0, 0.6023492392363033, 0.35422127975216294, 0.2467715189985823, 0.5963684134832621],
      ttip: [-118.742185,-656.951201875,1837700000.0,207.163683125,-686.6911225],
      pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]  
  });
});
</script></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately something like this is not supported - you need to use tooltip.formatter and there use that to get proper values. However, there is another solution, see: http://jsfiddle.net/F2uMR/2/

Instead of using `series.ttip` use `point.ttip`:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'max(rec(9))',
        data: [{
            y: 1.0,
            ttip: 307
        }, {
            y: 0.034440171953752756,
            ttip: -1589
        }, {
            y: 0.9724749421689427,
            ttip: 500000
        }, {
            y: 0.9937086214393859,
            ttip: 0.91
        }, {
            y: 0.021795139861960203,
            ttip: -1600
        }],
        ttip: [307.54340875, -1595.182889375, 5045200000.0, 831.187495625, -1664.2022475],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
```

and set fot tooltip: `pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>{point.options.ttip:,.2f}</b><br/>'`.

Comment: Hi @Pawel, thanks for the suggestion!
I was trying to work around the problem with a Formatter, like you say, but the other option is interesting!
A bit verbose, maybe, but I am going to generate the above code programmatically on the server side... Thanks!